# AWS API Gateway Signature

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, httpwebrequest, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to sign my requests to the amazon gateway. But every time when I try to send a POST request it tells me that my signature has been expired. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Post an example of your signed request, with a portion of the aws access key id and anything else you consider sensitive obscured.  (The signature itself doesn't contain anything "reversible.")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have some problem with getting the time or something like that. I had the problem with the payload. So if you are making GET request your payload is an **EMPTY STRING**. Otherwise it should be hashed Json object. Here is example of how I do it in my application. The code can be raw, but I am 100000% it work, because I am using it every day.

```
const string RegionName = "eu-west-1"; //This is the regionName
const string ServiceName = "apigateway";
const string Algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
const string ContentType = "application/json";
const string Host = "apigateway.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
const string SignedHeaders = "content-type;host;x-amz-date";

public static WebRequest RequestGet(string canonicalUri, string canonicalQueriString, string jsonString) {
    string hashedRequestPayload = CreateRequestPayload("");

    string authorization = Sign(hashedRequestPayload, "GET", canonicalUri, canonicalQueriString);
    string requestDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + "Z";

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://" + Host + canonicalUri);

    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
    webRequest.Headers.Add("X-Amz-date", requestDate);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("x-amz-content-sha256", hashedRequestPayload);


    return webRequest;
}

public static WebRequest RequestPost(string canonicalUri, string canonicalQueriString, string jsonString)
{
    string hashedRequestPayload = CreateRequestPayload(jsonString);

    string authorization = Sign(hashedRequestPayload, "POST", canonicalUri, canonicalQueriString);
    string requestDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + "Z";

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://" + Host + canonicalUri);

    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
    webRequest.Headers.Add("X-Amz-date", requestDate);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
    webRequest.Headers.Add("x-amz-content-sha256", hashedRequestPayload);
    webRequest.ContentLength = jsonString.Length;

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(jsonString);

    Stream newStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


    return webRequest;
}

private static string CreateRequestPayload(string jsonString) {
    //Here should be JSON object of the model we are sending with POST request
    //var jsonToSerialize = new { Data = String.Empty };

    //We parse empty string to the serializer if we are makeing GET request
    //string requestPayload = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(jsonToSerialize);
    string hashedRequestPayload = HexEncode(Hash(ToBytes(jsonString)));

    return hashedRequestPayload;
}

private static string Sign(string hashedRequestPayload, string requestMethod, string canonicalUri, string canonicalQueryString) {
    var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var accessKey = //Here place your app ACCESS_KEY
    var secretKey = //Here is a place for you app SECRET_KEY

    var dateStamp = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var requestDate = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss") + "Z";
    var credentialScope = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/aws4_request", dateStamp, RegionName, ServiceName);

    var headers = new SortedDictionary < string, string > {
            { "content-type", ContentType },
            { "host", Host  }, 
            { "x-amz-date", requestDate }
        };

    string canonicalHeaders = string.Join("\n", headers.Select(x => x.Key.ToLowerInvariant() + ":" + x.Value.Trim())) + "\n";

    // Task 1: Create a Canonical Request For Signature Version 4
    string canonicalRequest = requestMethod + "\n" + canonicalUri + "\n" + canonicalQueryString + "\n" + canonicalHeaders + "\n" + SignedHeaders + "\n" + hashedRequestPayload;
    string hashedCanonicalRequest = HexEncode(Hash(ToBytes(canonicalRequest)));

    // Task 2: Create a String to Sign for Signature Version 4
    string stringToSign = Algorithm + "\n" + requestDate + "\n" + credentialScope + "\n" + hashedCanonicalRequest;

    // Task 3: Calculate the AWS Signature Version 4
    byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(secretKey, dateStamp, RegionName, ServiceName);
    string signature = HexEncode(HmacSha256(stringToSign, signingKey));

    // Task 4: Prepare a signed request
    // Authorization: algorithm Credential=access key ID/credential scope, SignedHeadaers=SignedHeaders, Signature=signature

    string authorization = string.Format("{0} Credential={1}/{2}/{3}/{4}/aws4_request, SignedHeaders={5}, Signature={6}",
    Algorithm, accessKey, dateStamp, RegionName, ServiceName, SignedHeaders, signature);

    return authorization;
}

private static byte[] GetSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName) {
    byte[] kDate = HmacSha256(dateStamp, ToBytes("AWS4" + key));
    byte[] kRegion = HmacSha256(regionName, kDate);
    byte[] kService = HmacSha256(serviceName, kRegion);
    return HmacSha256("aws4_request", kService);
}

private static byte[] ToBytes(string str) {
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToCharArray());
}

private static string HexEncode(byte[] bytes) {
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
}

private static byte[] Hash(byte[] bytes) {
    return SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytes);
}

private static byte[] HmacSha256(string data, byte[] key) {
    return new HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(ToBytes(data));
}
```

So for example if I want to get all the APIs that are deployed in the Gateway I am doing like this:

```
using(WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse()) {
    StreamReader responseReader = new   StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseJson = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
} catch (WebException) {
    //Doing something when exception has been thrown
}
```

Here is the interesting part of creating a API Key. First you need to make your raw payload and then pass it to the methods I gave you above:

```
string payload = "{ \"name\" : \"" + name + "\", \"description\" : \"" + description.Trim() + "\", \"enabled\" : \"True\", \"stageKeys\" : [ ] }";

WebRequest webRequest = RequestSignerAWS.RequestPost("/apikeys", "", payload);
```

And make sure you are getting the time of the creating the request, because this will cause you the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through your code, but most likely the singing has been expired, cuz I am not setting the time in the headers in postman.

Comment: How can I post to API GateWay endpoints to create a resource. My api is backed by AWS lambda and I sign in to API using cognito. I use API GateWay SDK for using it in Javascript, how to call endpoints  with c#?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code!  For my case, I had to change ServiceName to "execute-api", and my host string is quite a bit different (this is the Invoke URL on the deployed Stage of the API you want to hit).  

The other thing that was important was to add good code to read the response when an error was returned - Amazon sends back pretty helpful messages to point you to what's wrong with your signature

Comment: Hi, I am using same code, I have added mapping template in AWS API gateway method, but In lambda function I am not getting parameters?

Comment: Thank you Sir for your kind contribution. This example made a HUGE difference. I was ready to throw in the towel.

Comment: Hi, I am calling aws api using same code, but I am getting 403:forbidden exception. but when I am hitting that api through postman its executed successfully

Comment: I had to alter the service name to 'execute-api' as well. I also had to change the Host to '<API_ID>.execute-api.<REGION>.amazonaws.com' where <API_ID> is the AWS generated api id and <REGION> is the AWS region (obviously).

Comment: Hi, I am calling aws GET api using same code, but I am getting 403:forbidden exception. but when I am hitting that api through postman its executed successfully

Comment: Running this code with the appropriate changes to the Host format, I always get the error: SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

You can look or use the code in this project for sending requests to API gateway:
https://github.com/ronenfe/Addons.AwsSdk
It uses this code for the signing:
https://github.com/tsibelman/aws-signer-v4-dot-net .