# AWS API Gateway 403:Forbidden

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call API of AWS through c#. It is getting me exception as

> “The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden” .

But when I call same API from postman it works. I am creating signature as mentioned in answer by Vasil Indzhev
[AWS API Gateway Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906755/aws-api-gateway-signature)

Answer (score 0):

The error could be returned from CORS rejection at the API path during preflight request. Since Postman does not do the preflight request, this could be the reason why you are seeing the request works in Postman.

Comment: How do i disable preflight in HttpClient?